# Can I inject provider into factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I want to create a httpRequestInterceptor to use in .config of application.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
```

I have this provider and factory of RequestInterceptor:

```
angular.module('app.services', [])
.provider('appProvider', [function () {
    var apiUrl = "http://url/api";
    var _authToken = null;
    var _currentUser = null;

    this.$get = function($q, $http, $cookieStore) {
        var service = {
            getAuthToken: function() {
                return _authToken ? 
                    $cookieStore.get('authToken') ? 
                        (_authToken = $cookieStore.get('authToken'), _authToken) :
                        '' : _authToken;
            }
        };  

        return service
    }
}])
.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', [function () {
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            config.headers = {'auth-toke': appProvider.getAuthToken()}
            return config;
        }
    };
}]);
```

I get error: Cannot read property 'getAuthToken' of undefined

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You need to inject the app provider, like this `.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', [function (app)`

Comment: Unknown Provider error

Answer (score 0):

Inject appProvider:

```
.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', ['appProvider', function (appProvider) {
     return {
        request: function(config) {
            config.headers = {'auth-toke': appProvider.getAuthToken()}
            return config;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Now I am getting: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/cdep?p0=appProvider%20%3C-%20httpRequestInterceptor%20%3C-%20$http%20%3C-%20$templateFactory%20%3C-%20$view%20%3C-%20$state

Comment: Remove $http from RequestInterceptor factory in $get.

Answer (score 0):

Add $injector and use it

```
.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function ($injector) {
 return {
    request: function(config) {
        config.headers = {'auth-toke': $injector.get('appProvider').getAuthToken()}
        return config;
    }
  };
}]);
```